# Retornar última entrada de cada produto

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

me ajudem. Estou com uma situação onde quero trazer apenas a última entrada de nota de cada produto para criação de um relatório.
Criei um select, porém existem produtos se repetindo onde não deveria. Veja o select:

```
SELECT P.CodProd, MAX(E.Entrada) Entrada, P.PrecoCustoUNSC,IE.ValorCaixa 
FROM Entradas E 
        INNER JOIN ItensEntrada IE ON E.Cod_Entrada=IE.Cod_Entrada 
        INNER JOIN Produtos P ON IE.CodProd=P.CodProd 
        WHERE IE.ValorCaixa>0 
GROUP BY P.CodProd, P.PrecoCustoUNSC, IE.ValorCaixa 
ORDER BY 1
```

---

Resultado:

```
CodProd Entrada                 PrecoCustoUNSC                          ValorCaixa
------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
000001  2019-08-20 00:00:00.000 3.0000000000                            3.0000000000
000001  2019-08-19 00:00:00.000 3.0000000000                            10.0000000000
000001  2019-08-23 00:00:00.000 3.0000000000                            15.0000000000
000002  2019-08-20 00:00:00.000 15.0000000000                           15.0000000000
000002  2019-08-23 00:00:00.000 15.0000000000                           65.0000000000
000003  2019-08-23 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           30.0000000000
000003  2019-09-06 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           50.0000000000
000004  2019-08-23 00:00:00.000 50.0000000000                           50.0000000000
000005  2019-09-04 00:00:00.000 5.0000000000                            5.0000000000
000006  2019-09-04 00:00:00.000 5.0000000000                            5.0000000000
000007  2019-09-04 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           30.0000000000
000008  2019-09-04 00:00:00.000 50.0000000000                           50.0000000000
000009  2019-09-05 00:00:00.000 69.0000000000                           69.0000000000
000010  2019-09-05 00:00:00.000 35.0000000000                           35.0000000000
000011  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 50.0000000000                           50.0000000000
000011  2019-09-06 00:00:00.000 50.0000000000                           60.0000000000
000012  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           30.0000000000
000013  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 15.0000000000                           15.0000000000
000014  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           30.0000000000
000015  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 13.0000000000                           13.0000000000
000015  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 13.0000000000                           6.5000000000
000016  2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 30.0000000000                           30.0000000000
```

Então, o produto 1 por exemplo está se repetindo, sendo que eu queria apenas o último registro (Entrada = '2019-08-23') que foi a última entrada do produto dele. Precisei relacionar pois na Entradas está a data da entrada, a ItensEntrada contem ValorCaixa que é o preço de custo onde quero comparar com o cadastro do produto que é o PrecoCustoUNSC.

Comment: E como saber qual é a última entrada de um produto? A coluna `Entrada` não é confiável, pois pode existir mais de uma entrada para um mesmo produto, em um mesmo dia.

Comment: O gerenciador de banco de dados é MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: SQL SERVER. É verdade, eu não tinha pensado nisso, podemos usar ao invés da entrada o campo COD_ENTRADA que é o número sequencial de cada nota.

Comment: As 3 linhas que você diz que se repetem apresentam diferentes valores para o campo ValorCaixa, um dos campos presentes na cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando-se a informação adicional postada nos comentários pelo autor do tópico - *podemos usar ao invés da entrada o campo COD_ENTRADA que é o número sequencial de cada nota* -, eis sugestão:

```
-- código #1 v2
with Ultimo as (
SELECT P.CodProd, E.Entrada, P.PrecoCustoUNSC, IE.ValorCaixa,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by P.CodProd order by E.Cod_Entrada desc)
  from Entradas E 
       inner join ItensEntrada as IE on E.Cod_Entrada = IE.Cod_Entrada 
       inner join Produtos as P on IE.CodProd = P.CodProd 
  where IE.ValorCaixa > 0 
)
SELECT CodProd, Entrada, PrecoCustoUNSC, ValorCaixa
  from Ultimo
  where seq = 1
  order by CodProd;
```

---

Na CTE `Ultimo` para cada produto é gerado um numerador sequencial (`seq`), iniciando de 1 para o mais recente (isto é, com maior valor de Cod_Entrada) e incrementando à medida que é mais antigo. Para acompanhar este passo basta executar o seguinte código:

```
-- código #2
SELECT P.CodProd, E.Entrada, P.PrecoCustoUNSC, IE.ValorCaixa,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by P.CodProd order by E.Cod_Entrada desc)
  from Entradas E 
      inner join ItensEntrada as IE on E.Cod_Entrada = IE.Cod_Entrada 
      inner join Produtos as P on IE.CodProd = P.CodProd 
  where IE.ValorCaixa > 0
  order by P.CodProd, E.Cod_Entrada desc;
```

Após, basta ler o resultado de `Ultimo`, filtrando por aqueles cujo valor de `seq` é 1.

Comment: José, bom dia! 

Confesso que não entendi muita coisa do teu código, não sou muito experiente ainda na área assim como você, mas deu certinho. É claro que vou estudar teu código inteiro pra entendê-lo melhor pra não precisar pedir ajudar por aqui novamente. Vc é show mano, mto obg!

Comment: @GiovaneFerreira Acrescentei uma explicação resumida ao final. Espero que facilite a compreensão.

Comment: show meu rei, vc é 10! Dei uma olhada tbm, ja deu pra entender certinho o que tu fez.

Answer (score -1):

Essa tarefa pode ser um pouco mais complexa que parece a primeira vista, então veja, eu vou colocar um código aqui só pra você fazer um teste, eu não sou um DBA experiente o bastante pra dizer se essa é a melhor técnica.
Também não sei qual o nome do campo que é chave primaria da sua tabela `ItensEntrada` então você mesmo corrige aí.

```sql
SELECT
    ie.CodProd,
    e.Entrada,
    p.PrecoCustoUNSC,
    ie.ValorCaixa
FROM (
    SELECT
        i1.CodProd,
        i1.Cod_Entrada,
        i1.ValorCaixa
    FROM ItensEntrada i1
    WHERE
        i1.CodItemEntrada = (SELECT MAX(i2.CodItemEntrada) FROM ItensEntrada i2 WHERE i2.CodProd = i1.CodProd)
) ie
INNER JOIN produtos p ON p.CodProd = ie.CodProd
INNER JOIN Entradas e ON e.Cod_Entrada = ie.Cod_Entrada
ORDER BY ie.CodProd
```